# What is the feminine equivalent of "guy"?

Tags: word-request, nouns

Is there a word that is the feminine equivalent of *guy*? I thought of *gal*, but I think it is used for a girl, or a young woman. I am looking for a word that can be used to generally mean *woman*, and similar to *guy*.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/addressing-a-group-of-women-as-you-guys (today we have a good harvest of "guys" and "gals" :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the writers of [this musical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guys_and_Dolls#References), it’s *gal*. In more recent times, however, *guy* seems to have become unisex.

Comment: Can we use of "guys" for a mixed gender population? Or do you prefer to say "ladies & Gentlemen"? But in a friendly gathering I think "ladies & Gentlemen" seems a little strange!

Comment: That is answered on [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/addressing-a-group-of-women-as-you-guys).

Comment: @user37324. _Ladies and gentlemen_ is normally quite formal. As I said in my answer, _guys_ does seem to be increasingly used to address men and women, but its use  depends on the relationship between the speaker and those addressed.

Comment: I think _gal_ is regarded as being a bit dismissive and I'd be reluctant to use it as a generic replacement for "guys."

Comment: I often hear (and use!) *guys* as a general term for a mixed sex group (and sometimes even for an all female one), but the singular *guy* still seems inappropriate for referring to a woman. In that case, usually *gal* or *girl* is the go-to rather than *guy*.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases "gal" can be used, and in some cases "girl" can be used. (for example "Girls night out" is more or less equivalent to "guys night out".) But although "girl" is sometimes used to refer to women of any age, it at least suggests a child or a young woman, and many women now consider it a mild put-down when used of an adult women, implying that women are never really mature. Once it was common to refer to a female workforce as "the office girls", but that would be taken as quite negative by many now.

There really isn't a female equivalent for "guy" in many usages. Some people use "guys" to mean "people", but I think that sounds odd, and depending on the context, perhaps wrong. There are many slang terms for "woman" but most of them have similar problems to "girl" or worse ones.  It very much depends on the specific audience. "Lady" or "ladies" almost always works, but is a bit more formal than "Guy" or "Guys".

Answer (score 0):

Guys seems to have a kind of casual almost affectionate ring that evokes a specifically male personna. The unisex usage seems a bit contrived, tag-along. Guy probably arose among men from sustained, all-male work, military, or school experience. Not having had many of those kinds of experiences women have evolved no generally informal terms for themselves. Maybe that will change.

Answer (score 0):

As guy probably came from the first name Guy, I would say that there isn't one to be used in the same way.  My guess is that sheila (as used in Australia) could be the equivalent, although I don't think it would go down quite as well.